# Sequential Clock divider

Tags: vhdl, frequency-divider

I'm new to VHDL programming.  I want to have frequency divider of an input clock signal by 2 consecutive integer x, y each of them last for 2 cycles.  Actually I wrote it only for x. How can have clock cycle last for two periods? below is my code,thanks for your reply.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity clk_divider is
            generic(
                    x:integer:=2;
                    y:integer:=3);
            port(   clk_in:in std_logic;
                    clk_out:out std_logic);
end entity;

architecture beh of clk_divider is
        begin
                process(clk_in)
                        variable tmp:std_logic:='0';
                        variable count1:integer:=0;
                        --variable count2:integer:=0;

                        begin
                            if (rising_edge(clk_in)) then
                                    count1:=count1+1;
                                    if(count1=x-1) then
                                        tmp:=not tmp;
                                        count1:=0;
                                    end if;
                            end if; 
                        clk_out<=tmp;
                        end process;
end architecture;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, clocks should be modified only through use of PLL/DCM, thus not made through use of ordinary logic.  The reason is that clock handling in and FPGA/ASIC requires separate routing and constraining, in for the tools to work correctly.

Instead of generating a derived clock, you can use the original clock, but then make an enable signal so for example a calculation does only update the result when the enable signal is asserted.